# Cannot redeclare the function error

Tags: php

```
function getContactActiveEmails($eid)
{
    global  $db;

    if ($eid) {
        $sql = "SELECT email FROM activeEmails WHERE id = $eid";
        return $db->GetCol($sql);
    }
}
```

I get the error "Cannot redeclare function `getContactActiveEmails`"

The line number it gives is the last line of the function - the }

All files are being called with `require_once`.  This is the only place in the entire codebase where `getContactActiveEmails` is being defined.  Why is this?

Comment: Do you have functions with the same name in different files, or multiple copies of the file with this function?

Comment: Maybe you're calling the function with the keyword "function" somewhere accidentally?

Comment: This is the only place where getContactActiveEmails is being defined.  It's called in two places elsewhere.
$emails = getContactActiveEmails($this->recipientID);
$emails = getContactActiveEmails($eid);

Comment: make sure you are not using built-in type function names as your user-defined function names

Comment: Is this function declared in some sort of loop?

Comment: GetCol($sql); // you have declared this function anywhere else ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is very clear from the error your function is defined twice hence you are getting the error.

I would recommend that check if the function is already defined before declaring it.

```
if (!function_exists('getContactActiveEmails'))
{
   function getContactActiveEmails($eid)
   {
      global  $db;

     if ($eid) {
         $sql = "SELECT email FROM activeEmails WHERE id = $eid";
         return $db->GetCol($sql);
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: That worked - hopefully we'll figure out the actual issue later on, but this gets me back to real work.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

solution by @Shakti Singh will work, but keep in mind that you are loosing control of your code - you do not know where is this function declared and what does it return, so I suggest looking for it

1. Try case insensitive search, many text editors and IDEs search case-sensitive by default and your function can be as well declared as `getcontactactiveemails` somewhere.
2. If still no luck make php say something about this function, using `Reflection` extension

Example usage of reflection:

```
if(function_exists('getContactActiveEmails')){
    $myfunc = new ReflectionFunction('getContactActiveEmails');
    echo 'Function is declared in '.$myfunc->getFileName().
         ' starting from line '.$myfunc->getStartLine().
         ' to '.$myfunc->getEndLine();
    die;
}
```

More about [Reflection](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionfunction.php)

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the same issue. I have a standard file called adhoc.inc.php which is imported into almost every php file on my site. With no changes being made to any code over night i started seeing the error

```
[13-Jul-2013 21:19:22 Australia/Sydney] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare checkloggedin() in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mycobber/util/adhoc.inc.php on line 4
```

Initially I only got it in a few files so i just commented out this import and it worked. Suddenly, again no changes, I was getting this in every file i loaded. I figured this wasn't me so I restarted my MAMP servers (apache and mysql) and then it went away.

Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: hmm ... question or answer? If the former, please post a ... [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) :-)

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs if you have your function defined in a loop, since you're trying to define it in each iteration.