# How can I check which file is a function in?

Tags: php, workflow

I'm working with PHP and sometimes, I want to find where the function being used is located. How can I do this easily without tracing through everything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually just do a quick

```
'grep -d recurse "function\ function_name" *
```

from the root of the project.

Comment: +1 Or use your editors find in files functionality. if it supports regexs you can do `function\sfunctionname`

Answer (score 0):

Use the `__FILE__` constant.

See here:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

Comment: -1 If he used `__FILE__` it would be placed in the source file where the function is defined. He doesn't know the where the function is defined.

Comment: I assume since this is a programming site he wants to know from the context of code. (as in his code needs to know where some function is defined) If he just can't find what file his function is in then it's a development environment issue and not a question that belongs here.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the notepad++ find in files function, works wonders.

Comment: I use this for my PC, but I am on a Mac.

Comment: ahh, in that case I do not know sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl+Click in IDE (NetBeans, PhpStorm) at function's name

Answer (score 0):

Add a logging class: Example here: http://llihp.blogspot.com/2011/05/php-logger-class.html

Answer (score 0):

[Cannot redeclare the function error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5982058/cannot-redeclare-the-function-error)

Check out the answer from dev-null-dweller here.  VERY handy extension.